# Custom sorting in news extension

Tags: sorting, typo3, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

According to the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/DeveloperManual/ExtendNews/ExtendFlexforms/Index.html#selectbox-sort-by) it is possible to extend the sorting options of the **news** extension in TYPO3 using:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['news']['orderByNews']
```

I did so in the `ext_tables.php` file:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['news']['orderByNews'] .= ',div_startdate';
```

Now I can see the new option in the selector, but the selection of it does nothing in the order of the displayed items.

What else should I do to get this sorting working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking in the TYPO3 Slack Channel and doing some research I have found that was needed to include the following line of TypoScript code in the **Setup** section of the Template to allow the sorting by the new field:

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.orderByAllowed := addToList(div_startdate)
```

Comment: only thing missing is how to also add a custom label to the new voice ...

Answer (score 0):

@webMan

Custom labels go to: your_ext/Resources/Private/Language/Overrides/News/locallang_be.xlf

```
<trans-unit id="flexforms_general.orderBy.div_startdate" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>Custom Startdate Label</source>
</trans-unit>
```